# XSD: Validate a sublist of element, order independent

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm searching how to create an XSD that validate those different cases:

**Case 1** (all elements)

```
...
<Childs>
 <ElementA/>
 <ElementB/>
 <ElementC/>
</Childs>
...
```

**Case 2** (Some elements missing, order can change)

```
...
<Childs>
 <ElementC/>
 <ElementA/>
</Childs>
...
```

**Case 3** (No children)

```
...
<Childs/>
...
```

**Case 4** (Every child can appear several times, in any order)

```
...
<Childs>
 <ElementA/>
 <ElementB/>
 <ElementA/>
 <ElementC/>
 <ElementA/>
</Childs>
...
```

I made several attempts:

**Attempt #1**

```
...
<xs:element name="Childs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="ElementA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="ElementB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="ElementC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

--> Doesn't work, because the order has to be respected (no `ElementA` could appear after one `ElementB` in this case

**Attempt #2**

```
...
<xs:element name="Childs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="ElementA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="ElementB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="ElementC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

It seems forbidden to set anything else than 1 in the `maxOccurs`

**Attempt #3**

```
...
<xs:element name="Childs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="ElementA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="ElementB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="ElementC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

As far I understand, I will be able to have as many elements that I want, but all elements would have to be of the same type.

So, did I misunderstood something or is there another element that I can do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Your #3 matches your need; as long as the name of the elements are different (which you suggest they are by using different suffixes), the types can be different...

Comment: Ok, it doesn't force to make a choice for one of my subelement and repeat it as many times I want?

Comment: No, you're ok because the choice itself is repeating. If anything, I would get rid of the minOccurs and maxOccurs at the element level, and leave those at the choice level. Easier to read, and with the same effect.

Comment: @PetruGardea Ok I see. In fact in my "real" case I've one of the subElement that has to appear 1 time(min and max set to 1 then), so I was hopping to use this minOccurs/maxOccurs, any idea how to make this possible?